# output of docker container

Tags: php, docker

I have this docker file:

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
COPY . /src/
WORKDIR /src/
CMD [ "php", "./src/index.php" ]
```

ANd I'm using this two commands to run it:

```
docker build -t php_script .
winpty docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app php_script
```

How can I receive the output of my script in the text file and not in the terminal and can I automatize the process? For example to start the script everyday in the certain time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run container and write result to a file:

`winpty docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app php_script >> /path/to/filename.txt`

For the daily task create a cronjob `cronjob -e` and add line like:

```
# every day at 01.00 AM
0 1 * * * winpty docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app php_script >> /path/to/filename.txt
```

Comment: bash: /path/to/filename.txt: Permission denied

Comment: `/path/`  was a example, you can use whatever you want, `~/on/your/home`, here you will have right to do it.
for crontab use sudo if neede